# Facebook like button dialog overflow issue

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-like

Using Facebook like button inside an app iframe, e.g.

[image: like button position]

The like button is usually positioned somewhere on the right part of the screen. The problem is that once the like button is clicked, the dialog that comes beneath it hides beyond the iframe container, e.g.

[image: overflow]

It is very easy to simply disable the dialog (using CSS), however, something I need the dialog.

What are the possible solutions for this? I expect there should be a method to trigger some overlay form or make the dialog to appear to-the-left of the like button rather than right.

Comment: I am having a similar issue. Did you fix it?

Comment: No, Facebook did not provide ability to change element align. You will simply need to move the element to the left end of the page or hide the comment dialog.

Comment: Funny that Facebook hasn't added yet any option to left-align the dialog.

Answer (score 2):

From the [Facebook 'Like Button' dev page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/)

'If the Like button is placed near the edge of an HTML element with the overflow property set to hidden, the flyout may be clipped or completely hidden when the button is clicked. This can be remedied by setting setting the overflow property to a value other than hidden, such as visible, scroll, or auto.'

Comment: I am not referring to a div container with overflow hidden. I am referring to the Facebook app-iframe window.

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar problem and this fixed. Add this to your stylesheet:

```
.fb-like span{overflow:visible !important; width:450px !important; margin-right:-375px;}
```